# Communication apps "jumping" to front without user input on Big Sur

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur, video-conference

Since I updated to Big Sur on my MacBookPro MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, i5) I have this very inconvenient situation where my communication apps, specifically Zoom, Slack and Discord, jump to the front without any action on my part.

Usually I have the app in the back, meaning I am either actively using another application, like writing something on visual studio code, IntelliJ, pycharm, or just have something else like Firefox or Mail opened in front of it. Then suddenly it jumps to front as if I had clicked on it or brought it to the front in some arcane way like "hitting cmd+tab" very fast.

It has become common place to be showing something on zoom screen share to my colleagues and then discord or slack to jump to the front plane on top of what I am showing, or when just talking with video open the zoom landing/main/app jumps to front obscuring my screen in the middle of the call.

It is very disruptive and frustrating to my workflow and it is happening at an alarming rate. Yesterday I had it happen to me 7 times, today it already happened once.

I had other weird problems too with Big Sur like the zoom link to open a call not immediately opening a new tab in my browser (actually it may take up to 2 minutes to open a new tab), but this is showing signs that it is going back to normal now.

Comment: Always good to have a bootable version of your earlier MacOS install to go back to when the first version of a new one has bugs that interfere with your work.

Comment: this isnt the solution Im looking for, but I'll keep it in mind, thanks.